# Can't find a worksheet which exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet in Excel with the name "Control". I'm receiving a msgbox saying it doesn't exists. After I click on "OK" I get an error of "invalid call of function or procedure and the debugger stops in this function:

```
Private Sub ClearData(dataSheet As Worksheet)
    'On Error Resume Next
        'dataSheet.rows(DataRow1 & ":" & dataSheet.rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        Sheets(dataSheet).UsedRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This function is used to clear the worksheet and the code before `'dataSheet.rows(DataRow1 & ":" & dataSheet.rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents` is commented because is raises error and I decided to modify to the line `Sheets(dataSheet).UsedRange.ClearContents` but the problem persists.

**EDIT** `ClearData` is called with this code:

```
Public Sub Init(rowNr As Integer, copyMap As CopyActionsMap, dataSheet As Worksheet)

    m_configRowNr = rowNr
    Set m_dataSheet = dataSheet
    m_dataRowNr = FindDataRow
    m_dataSheet.Cells(m_configRowNr, 1).Select 'select first cell in config row
    If (Not m_initialized) Then Set m_columnCopyConfigs = GetColumnCopyConfigs(copyMap) 'also sets m_count
    ClearData (m_dataSheet) 'Clean the existing data Now it says "object doenst support this method or property" after this: Private Sub ClearData(dataSheet As Worksheet) Sheets(dataSheet).Cells.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you calling `ClearData`?  You're not sending it a string are you? Because it is expecting a worksheet object.

Comment: Public Sub Init(rowNr As Integer, copyMap As CopyActionsMap, dataSheet As Worksheet)
    m_configRowNr = rowNr
    Set m_dataSheet = dataSheet
    m_dataRowNr = FindDataRow
    m_dataSheet.Cells(m_configRowNr, 1).Select 'select first cell in config row
    If (Not m_initialized) Then
        Set m_columnCopyConfigs = GetColumnCopyConfigs(copyMap) 'also sets m_count
        
        ClearData (m_dataSheet) 'Clean the existing data

Now it says "object doenst support this method or property" after this:

Private Sub ClearData(dataSheet As Worksheet)
   
        Sheets(dataSheet).Cells.Delete

Comment: You're sending it a worksheet object, and then treating it like a string.  Instead of `Sheets(dataSheet).UsedRange.ClearContents` it should be `dataSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents`.

Answer (score 2):

As @tigeravatar has mentioned in the comments below your question, you are trying to use a worksheet object as a string variable.

Try changing your code to

```
Private Sub ClearData(dataSheet As Worksheet)
    'On Error Resume Next
        'dataSheet.rows(DataRow1 & ":" & dataSheet.rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        dataSheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

If you want to clear the sheet by a specific string name instead, you should change your code to

```
Private Sub ClearData(dataSheet As String)
    'On Error Resume Next
        'dataSheet.rows(DataRow1 & ":" & dataSheet.rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        Sheets(dataSheet).UsedRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

And you can then clear the sheet named "Test Sheet" by calling

```
ClearData "Test Sheet"
```

Comment: It pass but raises the error "No config row found in sheet" :/

Comment: That does not sound like an Excel error but an error raised by the function `GetColumnCopyConfigs(copyMap)` perhapse? And that is a user defined function. If that is causing you any problems to solve, that may be best suited for another question.

Comment: private m_connectionSettingsSheet As Worksheet
Public ServerBaseAddress, Userid, Pwd As String
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_connectionSettingsSheet = GetWorkSheet("Control")
    Userid = ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("userName", "Control")
    Pwd = ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("password", "Control")
where ServerBaseAddress =ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("ServerBaseAddress", "Control") pass but if i set it to "m_connectionSettingsSheet.Range("ServerBaseAddress").value" it raises the error "Object variable or with block variable not set"... i change this, maybe is the cause?

Comment: It is imposible to debug a this. You need to as this in a new question where we can see the UDF's and how you call them.